# How to get primary category set via Yoast seo plugin in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have used a Yoast seo plugin and set primary category for product. But in front I cannot get primary category name.

Comment: You have to show what code you have so far.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you've tried so far and what error you're encountering; it's difficult to tell from this what you're asking us for.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Hi you can get using postmeta table.

```
   $taxonomy = 'product_cat'; 
   $primary_cat_id=get_post_meta($product->id,'_yoast_wpseo_primary_' . $taxonomy, true);
    if($primary_cat_id){
       $primary_cat = get_term($primary_cat_id, $taxonomy);
       if(isset($primary_cat->name)) 
           echo $primary_cat->name;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you bharat. It saves my lots of time

Comment: To anyone having issues with this, remember to update the slug for your taxonomy. This example uses '_yoast_wpseo_primary_product_cat'. If your taxonomy's slug is 'city', then you would use '_yoast_wpseo_primary_city' instead.

Answer (score 31):

The Yoast SEO plugin now has a dedicated function — `yoast_get_primary_term_id()` — for getting the primary term's ID:

```php
$primary_term_id = yoast_get_primary_term_id( 'taxonomy_slug', $post_id_or_object );
```

You can then use `get_term()` to get the `WP_Term` object:

```php
// Will return `false` if no primary term has been set
$primary_term_id = yoast_get_primary_term_id( 'taxonomy_slug', $post_id_or_object );

if ( $primary_term_id ) {
    /** @var WP_Term $primary_term */
    $primary_term = get_term( $primary_term_id );
}
```

For those scenarios where you just need the term's name, you can use `yoast_get_primary_term()`:

```php
// Will return an empty string if no primary term has been set
$primary_term_name = yoast_get_primary_term( 'taxonomy_slug', $post_id_or_object );
```

Comment: This is the 2021 answer and should be accepted as an approved one.

Comment: Using yoast_get_primary_term_id() now, and just want to add:
1. When the current post is in only one category, the function still returns that category. 2. When editing a post, and selecting multiple categories for the post, it seems impossible not to select a primary category as Yoast simply selects one for you which you can change if you want, at least that's my experience so far. This is a good thing in my opinion as yoast_get_primary_term_id() would always return something relevant.

Answer (score 9):

I could not get the accepted answer to work.
I modified [this](https://joshuawinn.com/using-yoasts-primary-category-in-wordpress-theme/) to fit my needs

```
$cat_name = ''; // I have this set in some shortcodes

if (!isset($cat_name) || $cat_name == '') {

  if ( class_exists('WPSEO_Primary_Term') ) {

    // Show the post's 'Primary' category, if this Yoast feature is available, & one is set. category can be replaced with custom terms

    $wpseo_primary_term = new WPSEO_Primary_Term( 'category', get_the_id() );

    $wpseo_primary_term = $wpseo_primary_term->get_primary_term();
    $term               = get_term( $wpseo_primary_term );

    if (is_wp_error($term)) {
        $categories = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'category');
        $cat_name = $categories[0]->name;
    } else {
        $cat_name = $term->name;
    }

  } else {
    $categories = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'category');
    $cat_name = $categories[0]->name;
  }
}

echo $cat_name;
```

I have edited a working example to be more self contained, I used it for custom taxonomy so used [get_the_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) instead of [get_the_category()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/). This code has not been tested in its current state.