# Wordpress main category with ghost categories

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I wonder if there is any possibility to select a "main" category for a post, but also select "ghost" categories, so that a wordpress post only shows the main category but also appears on the other categories.

Example page: https://interestingengineering.com/autonomous-cars

If you go to that page you get all posts within the category autonomous-cars. However if you open for example the article about "The Future of Flying: A Japanese Flying Car Takes to the Skies" the main category on that site is "industry/vehicles":

https://interestingengineering.com/the-future-of-flying-a-japanese-flying-car-takes-to-the-skies

For me the main category would be industry/vehicles and the other categories where the post appears would be ghost categories.

Also I would like to know if the permalink structure could be preserved. Above example shows root/slug, however I would like to have root/main_category/slug.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve what you want. I would recommend to use the Yoast SEO plugin as it includes all the features you need.

Since version 3.1 ([2016](https://yoast.com/yoast-seo-3-1/)) you can select the Primary Category, which allows to:

- You can [use the code from this valid answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800626/how-to-get-primary-category-set-via-yoast-seo-plugin-in-wordpress) from stack overflow to show only one category in your theme.
- If you use in the permalink settings of WordPress `/%category%/%postname%/` it will have your desired URL structure.

Comment: Yesterday I added Yoast SEO and set it up. However, I could not manage to find a settings page about categories. Where do I find it? The permalink is set as you suggested it, but when I select more than one category, the permalink only shows the postname.

Comment: Hi @Hans123 you need to check which is the main category of each post (like in this image: https://imgur.com/a/gC8wMqx). Regarding the permalinks it should work as it is a default setting in WordPress (https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/#structure-tags) if your server complies with the requirements specified in the docs. Could you share your theme and installed plugins and post a capture of your permalink settings?

Comment: Thank you. It works, although I had to adjust my theme to only display the main category as well afterwards.